# Can I assign a YAML anchor without assigning it to a key?

Tags: yaml

I want to effectively define a variable in YAML, then use it as a value in multiple places:

```
myvar_foo: &myvar_bar 1000
my_values:
  one: *myvar_bar
  two: *myvar_bar
```

It feels inelegant to me that I need to have `myvar_foo` in there. I never use it; I only use `myvar_bar`.

Is there any way to achieve this? Best I can think of is to use an obviously throwaway name like

```
_: &myvar_bar 1000
my_values:
  one: *myvar_bar
  two: *myvar_bar
```

or to assign the anchor the first time I use it

```
my_values:
  one: &myvar_bar 1000
  two: *myvar_bar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no variables in YAML. You don't *assign* anything in YAML. You are trying to apply programming language paradigms to a data serialization language.

The semantic of a YAML document's content is a weakly connected graph. Any value is a node in that graph. An anchor is simply a name for a node so that it can be referred to later. This means that:

- Your value (`1000`) is a node, because all content is stored in nodes.
- Since the graph is weakly connected, there must be a path from the root node to your value.
- Therefore, you cannot place the original value outside of the document content.

The second option you mentioned:

```yaml
my_values:
  one: &myvar_bar 1000
  two: *myvar_bar
```

is the natural way of doing this in YAML: On first occurrence, the value of the node is defined and named with an anchor. Each subsequent occurrence will then be serialized as an alias to that anchored node.

Now of course, the mere fact that YAML was not designed for what you want to do with it does not invalidate your goal. If you want to keep the value definition outside of your content tree **and have control over the code loading this YAML**, you could do:

```yaml
declare:
- &myvalue_bar 1000
begin:
  my_values:
    one: *myvar_bar
    two: *myvar_bar
```

Then, when loading, take the document tree from `root["begin"]` as the loaded value. You could even automate this by having a header like

```yaml
%YAML 1.2
--- !vars
declare:
- &myvar_bar 1000
begin:
  # snip
```

Then, you only need to register a constructor for `!vars` that returns the inner value of `begin`.

Comment: Thank you! Excellent, thorough and pragmatic answer. Took me a while to get the last example, so I’ll share my findings here for future reference. After some research, I believe “!vars” is a so-called “tag”, effectively introducing a new “vars” data type that the JSON parser I use can likely be configured to handle in some special way - such as only returning the inner value of “begin”. I assume “-- -!vars (And “%YAML 1.2” is simply a “directive” stating the YAML version.)

Comment: Can’t edit to fix my accidentally submitted half-edit. I was saying: I assume “--- !vars“ tags the document as a whole.

Comment: `%YAML 1.2` is usually superfluous, but I like having it when explicitly giving `---`, and I like giving `---` when setting the tag of the root node. Syntactically, you can just have `!vars` on an own line above `declare`.

Comment: And yes, `!var` is a tag, specifically, a *local* tag indicated by the single `!` (compared to global tags like `!!str` for strings). There are quite some examples on SO for how to deal with them in your preferred YAML implementation; sadly library documentation is often lacking here.

Comment: To be clear -- If I understand the answer from @flyx and the comment from the op -- the vars tag solution only works if you have control over the configuration of the yaml parser.  If creating yaml for some tool (e.g. helm or [yaml-online-parser](https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/ ), you ar stuck with the first option (unless that tool allows for configuration of the parser), correct?